# logging to sasl enabled server in iphone chatting app..?

Tags: iphone, xmpp

i am making a chat app in which you can chat with each other..i am using xmpp framework for iphone..

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/

i have started from here..

Now i can login to sasl disabled server  but cannot login to sasl enabled server..it gives error "not-authorised"..what should i do..?any idea..?any other app using sasl login ..??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can log in to your SASL-enabled server with an existing client.  Often in these scenarios, the SASL-enabled server isn't configured correctly.